# How to change/show permissions in C

Tags: c, linux, chmod

I am new to C programming and I'd like to implement chmod command on files of a dir and subdir. How can I change/show permissions with a C code? Could someone help with a example? I would appreciate if anyone can provide me a code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a chmod function. From [man 3p chmod](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/chmod.html):

```
SYNOPSIS
   #include <sys/stat.h>

   int chmod(const char *path, mode_t mode);

...
```

If you want to read the permissions, you'd use stat. From [man 3p stat](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/stat.html):

```
SYNOPSIS
   #include <sys/stat.h>

   int stat(const char *restrict path, struct stat *restrict buf);

...
```

If you want to do it recursively like you mentioned, you'll have to do the looping over results of `readdir` yourself. Caveat!: you will have to do setting the permissions from bottom-up, because, for example, if you set the top-directory to read-only, you will not be allowed to set anything below it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but can I find somwhere a full code about it?

Comment: I did, but I found just pieces.

Comment: @user304414: Did you try the versions of the man pages I linked? They have real examples below them.

Comment: Yes, I did, but those are just examples, not a full program. I can learn  just from a functioning program code.

Comment: @user304414: Those are full examples of the calls to these functions. If you want a full program, wrap it in a main, declare the necessary variables...

Answer (score 2):

with the GNU C library you should be able to do it directly with

```
int chmod (const char *filename, mode_t mode)
int chown (const char *filename, uid_t owner, gid_t group)
```

check it out [here](http://www.ia.pw.edu.pl/~wujek/dokumentacja/gnu/libc/libc_9.html).. all these functions are in `sys/stat.h`

Answer (score 1):

a example:(show/test permissions)

```
struct stat st; 
int ret = stat(filename, &st);
if(ret != 0) {
    return false;
}   
if((st.st_mode & S_IWOTH) == S_IWOTH) {

} else {

}
```